# Como formatar resposta de um comando bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Minha intenção é imprimir na tela o número de páginas de cada PDF em um determinado diretório. Eu até consegui fazer isso através do seguinte comando:

```
find "$PWD" -iname "*.pdf" | xargs -i pdfinfo {} | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'
```

Contudo, a resposta desse comando é somente o número de páginas de cada PDF, um em cada linha.

Minha dúvida é: como formatar a resposta do comando acima de forma a imprimir o nome de cada arquivo PDF junto com seu número de páginas, da seguinte forma:

```
nome_do_arquivo1.pdf : 230
nome_do_arquivo2.pdf : 123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução de uma linha é utilizar o `for` para iterar em todos os arquivos `*.pdf` do diretório atual, dando um `echo` no próprio nome do arquivo e concatenando o `:` com o retorno do número de páginas.

Exemplo:

```
$ for f in *.pdf; do echo $f : `pdfinfo $f | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'`; done
Shakespeare-A-comedia-dos-erros.pdf : 106
Shakespeare-a-tempestade.pdf : 119
Shakespeare-Hamlet.pdf : 192
```